# How to backup entire server with symbolic links present?

Tags: linux, centos, backup, cpanel, symlink

I'm trying to download a copy of my entire server (Linux with cPanel installed, running CentOS).

What I originally did was tar the entire server and then download the tar file. The problem with this was that when I went to unzip it on my home computer to make sure everything was there, I got a lot of error in WinRAR saying that it couldn't extract certain files.

After investigating it further I realized that the files it couldn't extract were symlinks.

I don't necessarily need to be able to use symlinks on my home computer, but it would be nice to have a backup of them in case they need to be re-created. If I were to unzip the file onto a Linux server, would the symlinks still work? so I could use them as reference in the future so know which files were linked to which?

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tar`. 
You should be able to get your symlinks on the target machine. You may however to have to replace some of them if you moved the root directory underneath some mount point.

In that case you can find the symlinks with

```
tar tvf the_backup.tar  | egrep -i 'symbolic link to /| -> /'
```

(or the equivalent tar tvf uses to display symlinks on your target machine)

This will show all symlinks pointing to "absolute" links (links **starting** with "/"), ie the most probable troublesome symlinks if you untar your backup underneath a subdir.

ex:

```
$ tar tvf the_backup.tar | egrep -i 'symbolic link to /| -> /'
?rwxrwxrwx 4000 500       0 Nov 05 17:00:00 2014 foo symbolic link to /bar
```

Note that:

- some tar (GNU tar, for ex) uses " -> xxx" to indicate a symlink to xxx
- some uses " symbolic link to xxx" instead (and other variation could occur ...)
- some (old) tar won't get rid of the starting '/' so be careful : if you use thos old version to untar on the target machine, file "/something" will go to "/something" instead of "/subdir_where_you_wanted_to_extract/something" ... It can hurt a lot. try on a small tar containing just "/dummyfile" first

Comment: You can also use cygwin / mobaXterm / etc on your windows OS to use the above command on your windows machine to find out 1) the complete list `tar tvf the_backup.tar` and 2) if you have some absolute links therein `tar tvf the_backup.tar | egrep -i 'symbolic link to /| -> /'` . Note that I use a very old OS and tar, here, so it may differ if you use the GNU ones ... my tar uses `symbolic link to ...`, GNU tar uses `-> ...` instead